# Control 'Ringtone and Alert Volume' from iOS 'Control Center'

Tags: sound-volume, alert

Is it possible to use the volume slider on the Control Center to control the Ringtone and Alert volume?

Or is it possible to add another volume slider to the Control Center?

Comment: That's not possible without jailbreaking.